# Updating Zend_Auth_Storage after edit users profile

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, zend-auth

I have following situation:
I have loged user, standard authentication with DB table

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()); 
$authAdapter->setTableName('users'); 
$authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('user_name'); 
$authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('password');
```

When user edits his profile, I save it into Db, but I need to update also storage (using standard Zend_Auth_Storage_Session). Is there any easy way how to do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to not use Zend_Auth's storage to hold information that's likely to change - by default it only holds the identity (for good reason).  I'd probably make a User class that wrapped all the Auth, ACL (and probably profile) functionality that uses a static get_current() method to load the user stashed in the session.  This bypasses all the consistency issues you run into when stuffing it into the session as well as giving you a single point from which to implement caching if/when you actually need the performance boost.

Answer (score 8):

```
$user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
$user->newValue = 'new value';
```

Assuming you are updating the session data in the same statement you are updating the database in there is no need to call the db again.

Answer (score 4):

I have done it like this, it works, but I don't know if there is not some better way,how to do it

```
$user_data = User::getUser($user_id)->toArray();
unset($user_data['password']);

$std_user = new stdClass();

foreach ($user_data as $key => $value)
{
   $std_user->$key = $value;
}

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();     
$auth->getStorage()->write($std_user);
```